# How to route AWS Route53 naked domain to my nginx Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I bought my domain (banuka.com) from the `Namecheap`. And created an `AWS` Route53 public hosted zone.

And also I added the `Nameservers` copied from that above hosted zone to the Namescheap DNS servers.

And I created a simple nginx server in an `EC2` and created 2 records;

```
banuka.com              A          <IP-OF-EC2>
nginx.banuka.com        A          <IP-OF-EC2>
```

My problem is, `http://nginx.banuka.com` works but not the `banuka.com`. Accessing just `http://banuka.com` give me "This site can’t be reached" in browser.

Can someone help me to fix this?

When I try to dig the `banuka.com`, it gives the following result

```
➜  ~ dig banuka.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> banuka.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32429
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jananath.com.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
banuka.com.     454 IN  SOA ns-920.awsdns-51.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 2a02:2457:30c:101::11#53(2a02:2457:30c:101::11)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 27 15:31:54 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

Can someone help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried using the Route 53 Alias records, pointing banuka.com to your A record ? As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Comment: @RicardoSueiras an EC2 instance is not a valid target for an Alias record. Also there is no need for an alias record here since there is a static IP address.

Comment: When I use online DNS testing tools to lookup `banuka.com` it appears to be configured to direct to forsale.hugedomainsdns.com. It doesn't not appear that you actually own this domain name. If you did buy this domain from Namecheap, then you have not configured Namecheap to use Route53 DNS servers for your domain yet.

Comment: I had assumed that in the original question that these two EC2-IPs were what he was referring to, hence suggesting Alias records.